# Ways of painting $N$ distinct boxes with $N-k$ colours where each colour must be used at least once

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $N$ distinct boxes, and I'm given $N-k$ colours to paint these boxes but I must use each colour at least once. So in the end, there will be at least one box of every colour. How many ways are there to paint the $N$ boxes?

What I've tried is that if I know the number of repetitions of each colour, then we can write the number of ways to paint it that.

Let $a_i\geq 1$ denote the number of boxes painted with colour $i$ where $1\leq i \leq N-k$.

Then each $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-k}\}$ corresponds to a configuration of the paintings where $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-k} a_j = N.$$ 
Let $A$ be the set of all possible sets$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-k}\}$.

For a fixed $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-k}\}\in A$, the number of ways is
$$\frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^{n-k} a_j!}$$
So the total number of ways is obtained by summing over all configurations, that is,

$$\sum_{a\in A} \frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^{N-k} a_j!}$$

Is this the best I can do and can this be simplified to a simpler expression? Is there another way to count this problem?

Comment: Does the order matter?  Is red, red, blue different from blue, red, red?

Comment: There is indeed another way to count the problem: running inclusion-exclusion on the events that color $i$ isn't used.  Alternatively, one may skip ahead to a final answer using [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and accounting for which partition received which color, giving an answer of $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}N\\N-k\end{smallmatrix}\right\}(N-k)!$ (*note that the inclusion-exclusion argument is one of the ways to arrive at a formula for stirling numbers in the first place*).

Comment: @RossMillikan yes the order matters.

Comment: @JMoravitz From my understanding the stirling number of the second kind $S(N,N-k)$ is the number of elements in $A$. Where do you get the $(N-k)!$ from?

Comment: @videlity no, $S(N,N-k)$ is not related to the number of elements in $A$.  The number of elements in $A$ are instead more closely related to the *multichoose* function $\left(\binom{n}{r}\right)$ after a slight modification.  Using the balls and boxes analogy, the number in $A$ that counts the number of ways to put indistinct balls (*our boxes in our problem*) in distinct boxes (*our colors in our problem*) such that at least one ball per box.  The stirling number of second kind counts the number of ways to have distinct balls (*our boxes*) and **indistinct boxes** (*our colors*).

Comment: Each with at least one per box.  That is to say, the stirling number counts the number of ways we can separate our $N$ boxes in our problem into $(N-k)$ groups.  Once separated into groups though, we haven't yet painted them and so we still need to decide which group gets which color.  The multiplication by $(N-k)!$ is for us deciding which group gets what color.